# How to make @Html.EditorFor invisible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I am just deleting the editor fields that I dont' want the user to see in the View , their data becomes null, I want to keep the data, but ,I don't want the user to edit it.

```
  <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>


            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parent_directory)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.parent_directory)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Add" />
            </p>
```

The @Html.EditorFor I am referring to is model.parent_directory. Can anyone suggest a solution that doesn't involve js ? I tried using DisplayFor instead of EditorFor and I still get a null value.

Comment: why dont you use a hidden field?

Comment: something like this perhaps,    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.hiddevalue), does that help answer?@DDavid

Comment: if you don't want the user to edit .. then you can use `readonly` attribute ... `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name,new{ @readonly="readonly" })`

Comment: Html.HiddenFor is what you want.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please take a look at this MSDN page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx

According to that page, you can't provide html attributes as a parameter for obvious reasons. Because `EditorFor` can be an `input` field or `select` and their html attributes differs from one another.

If you just want to hide it temporarily and show it later to the user, you can use `@Html.TextBoxFor`. You can find out more about `TextBoxFor` overloads at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx

e.g:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {style = 'display:none'})
```

if you want to keep these details hidden throughout the process, you can use `@Html.HiddenFor`

e.g

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use hidden fields for this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with:

```
@Html.Editor("WContractID", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "display: none" } })
```

Comment: Format your code section and provide some explanation around your answer. Please note that your answer looks similar to highly voted/accepted answer for this question. So improve your answer.

Comment: This answer contradicts the accepted answer, and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the fields and don't allow users to edit, you can make them  read only..

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new {@readonly = "readonly" })
```

If you don't want to show the fields to user and just need to hold data you can use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
```